# Weird line appears on 3D cube attempt

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

### First things first

I'm very new to OpenGL and game development at all. Perhaps I'll miss some important code or did something terrible in my code. Please feel free to ask for more information in comments.

### Problem

I've tried to draw a 3D cube made out of single lines. It works as expected but a *weird* line appears.
The *weird* line moves from **0,0,1** to **1,1,0**

I colored my lines with different (solid) colors. The *weird* line has a gradient.

[image: wild line appears apparently]

### Okay, time for some code

Since this is a lot of code, I'll try to post the minimum. As I said before, feel free to ask for more.

**The method that draws my cube**

```
private void drawBlock(Position pos) {
    int x = pos.x, y = pos.y, z = pos.z;

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINE_STRIP);

    GL11.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    // 0,0,0 -> 5,0,0
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y, z);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y, z);

    // 0,0,0 -> 0,5,0
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y, z);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y + blockSize, z);

    // 0,0,0 -> 0,0,5
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y, z);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y, z + blockSize);


    GL11.glColor4f(0.1f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
    // 5,0,5 -> 0,0,5
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y, z + blockSize);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y, z + blockSize);

    // 5,0,5 -> 5,5,5
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y, z + blockSize);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y + blockSize, z + blockSize);

    // 5,0,5 -> 5,0,0
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y, z + blockSize);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y, z);


    GL11.glColor4f(0.9f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 1);
    // 0,5,5 -> 0,0,5
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y + blockSize, z + blockSize);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y, z + blockSize);

    // 0,5,5 -> 5,5,5
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y + blockSize, z + blockSize);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y + blockSize, z + blockSize);

    // 0,5,5 -> 0,5,0
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y + blockSize, z + blockSize);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y + blockSize, z);

    GL11.glColor4f(1, 0.75f, 0, 1);
    // 5,5,0 -> 5,0,0
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y + blockSize, z);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y, z);

    // 5,5,0 -> 0,5,0
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y + blockSize, z);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x, y + blockSize, z);

    // 5,5,0 -> 5,5,5
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y + blockSize, z);
    GL11.glVertex3i(x + blockSize, y + blockSize, z + blockSize);

    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

**OpenGL Initialization**

```
public void init3D() {
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();

    GLU.gluPerspective((float) 100, width / height, 0.001f, 1000);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    GL11.glClearDepth(1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINES);` instead of line strip,

line_strip is a sequence of connected line where the sequence P1, P2, P3, P4 gives the lines P1-P2, P2-P3, P3-P4 and so on while `GL_LINES` would give only P1-P2 and P3-P4